# HTML offsetLeft delays to change

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, vue.js

I have four `canvas` in my screen, positioned two above and two below.

Each one have a button that makes possible to maximize the canvas, hiding   the others.

This button is positioned above each canvas, with absolute position based on `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` of the canvas.

However, when I maximize or minimize a canvas, the button formula updates only the `width` property.

The strange thing is that if I resize the screen, which also calls `resize` function, everything goes to the right place.

[image: Initial screen]

[image: After maximizing]

[image: Then after resizing screen]

**EDIT:** Additional information: I  am using VueJS and, in order to hide the other canvas, I apply `v-show="false"` to them parent `divs`, which only applies `display: none`.

**Some snippets:**

Initial resize and listener:

```
window.onload = function () {
    resizeAll();
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeAll, false);
};
```

The resize hub:

```
function resizeAll () {
    vue.$refs.panelOne.resizeDefault();
    // ...
    vue.$refs.panelN.resizeDefault();
}
```

The panel's resize default and resize method. The "**expandStyles**" is the css styles applied to the button:

```
resizeDefault() {
        let dimensions;
        if (this.expanded) {
            dimensions = getScreenDimensions();
        } else {
            dimensions = getHalfScreenDimensions();
        }
        this.resize(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
    }

resize (width, height) {
        this.canvas.width = width;
        this.canvas.height = height;
        this.expandStyles.top = (this.canvas.offsetTop + 10) + 'px';
        this.expandStyles.left = (this.canvas.offsetLeft + this.canvas.width - 40) + 'px';
        drawInterface.redraw();
    }
```

And finally, the dimension getters:

```
function getScreenDimensions () {
    return {
        width: window.innerWidth - 310,
        height: window.innerHeight * 0.92
    };
}

function getHalfScreenDimensions () {
    return {
        width: (window.innerWidth - 310) / 2,
        height: (window.innerHeight * 0.92) / 2
    };
}
```

Comment: You probably want to attach the whole snippet so people would be able to help you. If your snippet can't be separated from the Vue, you can use https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: Try to resize your canvas and next redraw your button. The offsetTop and Left values of the canvas are maybe not updated when you redraw your button. If it continue to do not work, use a setTimeOut.

Comment: Added more snippets. Basically, applying setTimeout it works. However, I'd like to pick a more straightforward solution. If nothing else works, I'd glad to accept the answer.

Comment: Why don't you set the buttons position with css so it will automatically be recalculated by the browser? E.g.: `canvas { display:absolute|relative }` and `canvas > button {position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with  S.P.H.I.N.X , it seems like the problem lies with propagation of reactive properties in this.expandStyles to actual DOM. Would be useful if you can share the part of the template which has your canvases and positioning application.

Meanwhile, if setTimeOut doesn't feel right to you, you may do things more "Vue-way" by using [Vue: nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to set order of operations (styles recalculation, redraw).